# Two Headed Giant Sealed Events Card Trading

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-drafting, mtg-two-headed-giant

Origins is being released soon, and I plan on going to the THG prerelease for the first time. Me and my partner have been running pull simulations to see what deck strats come up often. We are noticing that we often get cards necessary for the other's strategy.

Is it legal to trade them cards before the rounds start?

Comment: The title of the question asks about sealed. The body of the question asks about draft. Which one do you mean to ask about?

Comment: Prerelease is what I'm referring to, I think that's considered sealed. I'm not exactly an expert :P.

Comment: @Falcondance where are you running pull simulations? I'd love to try that out haha I've never heard of that before but I'd love to get some practice in for this weekend.

Comment: @RobertWertz http://mtgen.net/ori/#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only are you allowed to share cards, you are as a team considered to have a single card pool that you build your decks from. Section 9.6 of the [Tournament rules](http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_16jun15_en_0.pdf) says

> ### Two-Headed Giant Limited Rules
>
> All the rules for Limited Tournaments (Section 7) apply, except as described below.
>
> The DCI recommends that **each team** receive eight boosters per team for Two-Headed Giant Sealed Deck tournaments and six boosters per team for Two-Headed Giant Booster Draft tournaments. For the recommended product mix for the current block, refer to Appendix D.
>
> **Cards not used in a team’s starting decks are considered a shared sideboard by the two players that both players can access.**

Comment: I don't think the number of packs part applies to prereleases, though - I think you just get two entire prerelease packs. That'd mean a total of 12 normal boosters plus the two seeded ones! (see http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/magic-origins-prerelease-primer-2015-07-06)

Comment: ^ This thing is true.